# Thread inside thread trying to invoke and update ui

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I have on winform with a textbox and on textchanged executes a background thread:

```
private void txtFathersLast_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => WaitWhileUserTyping());
}
private void WaitWhileUserTyping()
        {
            var keepWaiting = true;

            while (keepWaiting)
            {
                _keyPressed = false;

                Thread.Sleep(TypingDelay);

                keepWaiting = _keyPressed;
            }

            Invoke((MethodInvoker)(ExecuteSearch));

            _waiting = false;
        }


private void ExecuteSearch()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(200);

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {

                using (DataReference.SearchWCF search = new DataReference.SearchWCF())
                {
                    _similaritySearchResults = search.SearchPersonBySimilarity(txtFathersLast.Text, txtMothersLast.Text, txtName.Text, DateTime.Now, 10);
                }

            }).ContinueWith(t=>{

                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        if (_similaritySearchResults != null && _similaritySearchResults.Tables["data"].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            DataTable dt = _similaritySearchResults.Tables["data"];

                            Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraTile newTile = null;

                            for (int index = 0; index < dt.Rows.Count; index++)
                            {
                                newTile = new Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraTile("Person X");
                                newTile.Control = new CustomControls.Controls.PersonResult("123", "123", index + 150);
                                newTile.Tag = new Guid("90D27721-7315-4B86-9CFD-4F7D02921E9A");
                                newTile.DoubleClick += TileDoubleClick;
                                tilePanel.Tiles.Add(newTile);
                            }
                        }

                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_similaritySearchResults != null && _similaritySearchResults.Tables["data"].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataTable dt = _similaritySearchResults.Tables["data"];

                        Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraTile newTile = null;

                        for (int index = 0; index < dt.Rows.Count; index++)
                        {
                            newTile = new Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraTile("Person X");
                            newTile.Control = new CustomControls.Controls.PersonResult("123", "123", index + 150);
                            newTile.Tag = new Guid("90D27721-7315-4B86-9CFD-4F7D02921E9A");
                            newTile.DoubleClick += TileDoubleClick;
                            tilePanel.Tiles.Add(newTile);
                        }
                    }
                }




            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());


        }
```

This is working fine, the application goes to a database then get results and update the UI, adding tiles to a control depending of the number of records returned by database.

Now, the problem comes when I try to add another background thread into my custom control:

new CustomControls.Controls.PersonResult("123", "123", index + 150);

The code for the control is:

```
protected override void InitLayout()
        {
            // if I comment this then everything works fine
            // but if I leave this, then the UI freezes!!
            GetPictureAsync();

            base.InitLayout();
        }

/// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        private void GetPictureAsync()
        {
            // This line needs to happen on the UI thread...
            TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();


            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Random sleep = new Random();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleep.Next(1000,3000));
                if (this.pbPhoto.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.pbPhoto.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        this.Load(@"E:\Photos\" + PhotoId.ToString() + ".jpg");
                        //this.pbPhoto.Image = Utility.Common.GetResourceImage("woman_sample.jpg");
                    }));
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Load(@"E:\Photos\" + PhotoId.ToString() + ".jpg");
                    //this.pbPhoto.Image = Utility.Common.GetResourceImage("woman_sample.jpg");
                }


            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiScheduler);
        }
```

So the problem seems to be that I first execute a thread for looking when to start search, then inside that thread I run another thread in order to get data from database, and then each control updated in the UI will run another thread to get a picture and update a picturebox.

Anyone knows how to solve this? or a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
new CustomControls.Controls.PersonResult("123", "123", index + 150)
```

Is "123" a literal string, or are they being read from UI controls. For example,

```
new CustomControls.Controls.PersonResult(txtFathersName.Text", txtMothersName.Text, index + 150)
```

i cant test it right now, but isnt accessing the Text property not allowed from a thread other than the one that created the control?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in you forcing the Task in `GetPictureAsync` to execute on UI thread and then you are calling `Thread.Sleep()`. This [update UI in Task using TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418208/update-ui-in-task-using-taskscheduler-fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext) question tackles the same problem as you are having. I would rewrite your code as:

```
private void async GetPictureAsync()
{
    Random sleep = new Random();
    await TaskEx.Delay(sleep.Next(1000,3000));
    this.Load(@"E:\Photos\" + PhotoId.ToString() + ".jpg");
}
```